# Failed to Connect to Database in SQL EXPRESS 2010 from Java Application

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having problems trying to connect from a Java application (Netbeans IDE 8.0.2) to a database in SQL EXPRESS 2010. I know that the connection parameters are correct since if I try to make the connection running the application from Netbeans it works fine, but If I try to make the connection running the aplication with the .jar, the try-catch shows me the following error:

```
Com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId: ad61b2cf-071d-4561-9416-c31f8e918a34
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:68)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3132)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:704)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:54)
    at sqlserver.SqlServer.checkNewConnection(SqlServer.java:67)
    at view.Dialogs.configConnection(Dialogs.java:269)
    at demosocketserial.DemoSocketSerial.checkConnection(DemoSocketSerial.java:211)
    at demosocketserial.DemoSocketSerial.main(DemoSocketSerial.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:41)
    ... 15 more
```

I already copied the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to the Windows System32 folder (that's how I made the connection successful from Netbeans) but I did not get the program to work from the .jar inside the "dist" folder.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. It sounds like the driver you are using to connect to your DBMS does not support integrated authentication. Try using a username/password combination that is created on SQL Server itself (as opposed to Windows authentication). This is generally better for portability anyways (if/when you host your application, you likely want explicit user credentials and not the Windows credentials of the logged-in user).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that what you say is correct, however, I am using the same driver to run the application from Netbeans and from the .jar and from Netbeans it works fine but from the .jar throws that exception. That makes me think that it is not a driver problem.

Comment: Right, I thought about that as well so I understand what you're saying. I'm wondering, however, if NetBeans technically makes the connection differently than the executable .jar file does. IE: perhaps it uses another driver.

Comment: What happens when you debug?